# gRPC as Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, grpc

I am experimenting with gRpc and have it running.  I am using .net core 3.1.  C# .  I am now attempting to install it as a windows service.  The machine is Win 10 Pro x64 .

I added the line as instructed to run it as a windows service...

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/self-hosted

            .UseWindowsService() // Enable running as a Windows service

            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

I publish to a folder (I never have used publish before) and voila... there is the publish folder.  I go to that folder and run (AS ADMINISTRATOR) installutil.  Yes it found the utility as i used the full path.  That path is

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe"

**Is this correct version to run for .net core?  Does that matter?**

So I run installutil {full-path-to}\grpcservice1.exe

I get...

> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///....\GrpcService1\GrpcService1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\publish\GrpcService1.exe'
>   or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
>   assembly manifest..

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong....
Suggestions?  I just following the example.

TIA

Comment: I have tried specifying x64 for the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`installutil.exe` looks for an [`Installer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer) class marked with the [`RunInstallerAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.runinstallerattribute) set to `true`. It only works for Windows Services written with .NET Framework.

In the case of .NET Core, I'd recommend publishing your application and registering a new service using [`sc create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create)/[`New-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service) as you would in the case of any other executable.

There are also [detailed docs in the .NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service#create-and-manage-the-windows-service) in case you needed something more detailed.